# Is a bounded solution of this PDE a constant?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I have a problem:

> Suppose a bounded function $u(x, y) \in C^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{2})$ is a solution of $$u_{xx}-2u_{xy}+\beta u_{yy}+2\beta u_{x}-\beta^{2} u_{y}=0.\tag{1}$$ 
>   Is it true that $u\equiv\operatorname{const}$ when
>
> a) $\beta>5$,
>
> b) $\beta<-5$?

I reduce equation to canonical form and have no other idea. Do you have one?

I get the following canonical form in case a):
$(\beta-1)u_{rr}+(\beta-1)u_{tt}+\beta(2-\beta)u_{r}-\sqrt{\beta-1}u_{t}=0$ in coordinates $r=x+y,t=-\sqrt{\beta-1}x$;

in case b):
$-2\sqrt{1-\beta}u_{rt}+\beta(\sqrt{1-\beta}-1)u_{r}+\beta(\sqrt{1-\beta}+1)u_{t}=0$ in coordinates $r=y+(1-\sqrt{1-\beta})x,t=y+(1+\sqrt{1-\beta})x$.

Comment: you are talking about general solution. Clearly $u=constant$ is always a solution without depending on $\beta$. However if you look at the discriminant $\Delta=1-\beta$, the equation is hyperbolic if $\beta<1$, parabolic if $\beta=1$ and elliptic if $\beta>1$.

Comment: It is not necessary to get general solution. The question is: Is there non-constant solution?

Comment: $u=\beta x+2y$.

Comment: @daulomb It is not bounded on $\mathbb{R}^{2}$.

Comment: We can find more particular solutions  such as $u=e^{-2\beta x}$ for $\beta>0$ and $u=e^{\beta y}$ for $\beta<0$ (which are both bounded). But to see that whether there are such solutions you eventually have to solve the equation by reducing it to its canonical forms.

Comment: @daulomb I think when $x<0$ and $\beta>0$ the expression $e^{-2\beta x}$ can get any predetermined value greater then $1$. By the way, i think that the real deal in this problem is to prove that there is no non-constant solution.

Comment: yes youre right they are not bounded so as I said you have to solve and see if there is a bounded solution I wish you good luck

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sketched answer:

Consider a linear change of coordinates $(x,y)\to (z,w)$:

$$\begin{align} x~=~& 2z+w, \cr 
y~=~&-\beta z +\alpha w, \cr  
\alpha~:=&~\frac{\beta}{\beta-2} , \cr 
\beta~\neq~& 2.\end{align}\tag{A}$$

Then the chain rule yields

$$\begin{align} \partial_z 
~=~&  2\partial_x - \beta \partial_y, \cr 
\partial_w ~=~&  \partial_x + \alpha \partial_y, \end{align}\tag{B}$$

and conversely,

$$\begin{align} (2\alpha+\beta) \partial_x ~=~&  \alpha\partial_z + \beta \partial_w, \cr  (2\alpha+\beta) \partial_y ~=~&   2\partial_w - \partial_z. \end{align}\tag{C}$$

Then OP's PDE (1) becomes "diagonal"

$$\begin{align} 0~=~&u_{xx}-2u_{xy}+\beta u_{yy} +2 \beta u_x -\beta^2 u_y\cr
~=~&u_{xx}-u_{yz}+ \beta u_z\cr
~=~&\frac{(\beta -2)^2}{\beta^2}u_{ww} +\frac{\beta -1}{\beta^2}u_{zz} + \beta u_z.  \end{align}\tag{D}$$

1. In the elliptic case $\beta>1 \wedge \beta\neq 2$ a [Liouville-type argument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_(complex_analysis)) prohibits non-constant bounded solutions.
2. In the hyperbolic case $\beta<1\wedge \beta\neq 0$, the dissipative $\beta u_z$-term prevents non-constant bounded solutions. A solution always increases exponentially at one of the asymptotic regions $z=\pm\infty$.
3. In the case $\beta=0$, the full solution to OP's PDE (1) is of the form
   $$u(x,y)=f(2x+y)+g(y),\tag{E}$$
   which clearly has non-constant bounded solutions.

Comment: Oh, thank you! Could you give some information on hyperbolic case or where can I read about hyperbolic PDE with dissipation?